# Symfony 4.3 Warning: chdir(): No such file or directory (errno 2)

Tags: symfony, composer-php, sylius

i try to add a new entity with the maker bundle of Symfony, but i can't get rid of this error , any help please :/ ?

it happen right after

```
 php bin/console make:entity

 Class name of the entity to create or update (e.g. GrumpyJellybean):
 > Customer

 Your entity already exists! So let's add some new fields!
PHP Fatal error:  During class fetch: Uncaught ErrorException: Warning: chdir(): No such file or directory (errno......
```

```
Error: During class fetch: Uncaught ErrorException: Warning: chdir(): No such file or directory (errno 2) in
   /Users/loic/Documents/TFE/cmi-3/vendor/symfony/debug/DebugClassLoader.php:458
  Stack trace:
  #0 phar:///Users/loic/Documents/TFE/cmi-3/vendor/phpstan/phpstan-shim/phpstan.phar/vendor/nikic/php-parser/l
  ib/PhpParser/Lexer/Emulative.php(12): spl_autoload_call('PhpParser\\Lexer')
  #1 /Users/loic/Documents/TFE/cmi-3/vendor/symfony/maker-bundle/src/Util/ClassSourceManipulator.php(63): spl_
  autoload_call('PhpParser\\Lexer...')
  #2 /Users/loic/Documents/TFE/cmi-3/vendor/symfony/maker-bundle/src/Maker/MakeEntity.php(743): Symfony\Bundle
  \MakerBundle\Util\ClassSourceManipulator->__construct('<?php\n\nnamespac...', false)
  #3 /Users/loic/Documents/TFE/cmi-3/vendor/symfony/maker-bundle/src/Maker/MakeEntity.php(167): Symfony\Bundle
  \MakerBundle\Maker\MakeEntity->createClassManipulator('/Users/loic/Doc...', Object(Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundl
  e\ConsoleStyle), false)
```

Comment: in case of doubt, first run `composer install` and clear the cache (`bin/console clear:cache`) and maybe that already helps.

Comment: Already tried, doesn't do the job

Comment: I find it weird, that `phpstan` appears in your stacktrace, because it doesn't make any sense why it would be called here, since it's not a dependency of the maker bundle... if you have it installed in your project, try removing it

Comment: Yes it's weird... well it's not installed and not required in composer.json

Comment: you could try the nuclear option and remove the vendor dir and `composer install` again, and see if phpstan is restored. if not, everything might work well. if it is ... you should find out, what pulls it in as a dependency and disable that package temporarily ...

Comment: Not working with the rebuild of the vendor :( 
Will continue checking.. that's annoying

Answer (score 0):

For now i got it working with

```
php bin/console make:entity --no-debug
```

it'll do the job but i still don't know what is happening.